# MySQL JSON_Array receiver type in Java

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-json

I have MySql query that will return as **JSON_Array** from MySql DB.

**Query:-**

```
SELECT id,
       JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(address))
FROM tb_address
GROUP BY id;
```

But I can't find proper variable type to receive that return value in **Java**. Someone can share the some code to handle the MySQL JSON_ARRAY.

Comment: would it not just be a String ?

Comment: Meaning need to parse to JSON format? (I'm quite new with MySQL JSON var)

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work.  I feel that if it works at all it may be a String and then you can maybe use Jackson or GSON to convert to JSON Obejcts

Comment: I haven't tried with String, Coz I thought it's rs.getArray("name") and received as Array or JSONArray. Will try receive as String and parse to JSON format.

Comment: i think simply you can return the string & convert it in to a object or json Oject. Ex:   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);